# How to allow third party apps to send e-mail to my clients, without exposing their e-mail address?

Tags: email, email-filter

So, I have a set of clients registered with a web application, and I would like some third party marketing services to be able to send e-mails to my users, on my behalf, based on their anonymous usage statistics.

However, the users are pretty sensitive to privacy so I cannot provide these services with the real user e-mail address.

Ideally, I'd provide the third party service with fake e-mail address (on my domain), and then forward the e-mail to the actual user e-mail. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please have a look on our [help center](http://superuser.com/help) to learn what type off questions you may ask here. Your current question is off-topic for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that if you're using postfix is to configure the alias file (/etc/postfix/aliases) to map the fake e-mail address on your domain to the client's actual email address.